# Why EnumWindows Not Working in service?

Tags: c++, winapi

I am just trying to enumerate all top level windows in a system. When I use EnumWindows function in a exe it enumerate all windows. Instead i use in the service I couldn't . it only enumerate

C:\Windows\System32\spool\tools\pnt\rpccp.exe
C:\Windows\System32\spool\tools\pnt\winfsmgr.exe

these exe only. I am creating a service as follows.

schService = CreateService(schSCManager, pServiceName,  pServiceName,    SERVICE_ALL_ACCESS,SERVICE_WIN32_OWN_PROCESS,SERVICE_AUTO_START,SERVICE_ERROR_NORMAL,pModuleFile, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL, NULL );

Is there is any permission needed to communicate another applications from this application(service). or what i do further to do enumwindows.

Comment: This is a windows programming concern.   Nothing to do with C++ (even if you happen to program for windows using C++, the problem is windows specific).

Answer (score 6):

Services run in session 0, with a non-interactive desktop. The interactive desktops run in session 1 and greater. `EnumWindows` enumerates windows in the desktop of the calling process. Your service does not run on an interactive user's desktop.

If you want to enumerate windows on a specific desktop, you will need to execute that process on that desktop. A service is the wrong tool for that job. If you absolutely need to know the information in a service, you need to use IPC between the service and another process that runs on the target desktop.

Comment: sorry @David Heffernan i dont know what is session 0 and session 1. will you give me a link to read what it is.

Comment: Start with a websearch for these terms: session 0 isolation